# Send mail in C# without Password

Tags: email, c#-4.0

I send email using below code. Its working fine. But how to send email without password. If I give empty string in senderPassword, I got below error
"Additional information: Transaction failed. The server response was: 5.7.1 : Client host rejected: Access denied".

I googled and found similar questions, but I didn't get correct solution. Please help me to solve this.

```
   SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
   smtp.Port = 587;
   smtp.Host = "myhost.com";
   smtp.EnableSsl = true;
   smtp.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
   smtp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(senderID, senderPassword);
   smtp.Timeout = 30000;

   MailMessage message = new MailMessage(senderID, To, Subject, Body);
   smtp.Send(message);
```

Comment: You need to have the password, because you need to authenticate to the email server - that's the case in most cases. I think most email servers require authentication these days, maybe not all of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change the authentication on the SMTP server. If you don't own the SMTP server then this is out of your control.

Comment: Can you let me know how to change the authentication on the SMTP server

Comment: That depends on which SMTP server you're using. It's usually quite a simple configuration change.